# How to clear the table by signal in django?

Tags: python, django, django-orm, truncate, django-signals

I have the following temporary model:

```
from django.db import models


class TempModel(models.Model):
    backup = False
    operation_type = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='operation type')
    device_type = models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name='device type')
    operation_datetime = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date and time of the payment')
    transaction_sum = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='sum of transactions')
    ...
    file = models.ForeignKey(to='core.RegistryFile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reg_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Date of register')
    operday = models.ForeignKey(to='OperDay', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'core'
```

I'd like to populate it with the temp data we need to compare with our internal table and truncate all the contents AFTER we use it every time we run the comparison.
What Django signal can I use to trigger data removal after every comparison? How may it look like?

Comment: Where are you doing the comparison? Could you provide some code for it? If you are doing the comparison in Django, you probably don't need signals here. You would probably be able to just delete the table's content after you got your comparison results.

Comment: It's done on the raw sql level after both models are populated with data. It's pretty long snippet of code to show, but to put is shortly - we left join these two tables and compare by condition, after comparison we should clear this temporary table.

Comment: So this happens completely outside of Django? Or are you using Django to execute the raw SQL for your comparison. As signals are specific to Django, you won't receive a signal for something that happens outside of its realm. Is anything stopping you from either importing your models to truncate the table or just truncate the table in SQL directly after your comparison ran?

Comment: We execute raw requests in the limits of the django project but in another application.

Comment: Couldn't you just import `TempModel` there and delete all instances, then?